# jquery assign different values to title element same class

Tags: jquery, html

EDITED- to FIX self inflicted errors.

I have a group of images and their URLS. They are all within the same class. I would like to assign a new title to the image based upon their index position. For example images 1-3 should be "Radiant Flowers", 4-6 would be glorious shrubs.

```
    $('.flower').each(function (index, value) { 
      console.log(index + ':' + $(this).attr('title'));
      if (index === 2)) {
        $('.flower').attr('title',"Radiant Flowers");
      } 
    });
```

the console shows the following output:

- 0:Mariposa Lily - Calochortus *species*
- 1:Mariposa Lily - Calochortus *species*
- 2:Mariposa Lily - Calochortus *species*
- 3:Radiant Flowers

So when I inspect the elements, the titles are all changed to Radiant Flowers.
What I have noticed is that when I can get this to work the code changes all values instead of the ones I had hoped to affect. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are logging your title on line two before you have changed it on line 4. Is that intentional? It looks like what you are doing should work.

Comment: I was wanting to make sure that values were touched by the program. Not knowing so much about jquery, I was leaning on the console to let me know that the code was doing something. The title shows up fine on the log but not on the actual page.

Comment: I've edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: your code changed all of the `.flower` elements, not just the ones you've intended it to. Check my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parseInt takes a bad argument: 'index' > 2
You should change it to parseInt(index) > 2, I think...

About the actual problem: you loop through your elements and you detect the one you want to modify... and then you modify all the elements with the class "flower".

The good way to do it would be to put this inside your "if": $(this).attr('title', "Radiant Flowers");

The reason is that $('.flower') will select ALL the elements with CSS class "flower", but you need to change only the current element. That is why, $(this) should work. Even better, you can use $(value) becase "value" is the variable that points to the current element in the foreach loop.

Comment: This is my guess too. You're trying to parseInt a boolean value as the ('index' > 2) will be evaluated (as false) and the result then parsed.

Answer (score 1):

What happened there, is that this line: `$('.flower').attr('title',"Radiant Flowers");` actually change **all** of the elements with class `flower`, and not the ones you wanted to change.

In order to fix this, in you code, change this:

```
if (index === 2)) {
    $('.flower').attr('title',"Radiant Flowers");
}
```

to

```
if (index > 2)) {
    $(this).attr('title',"Radiant Flowers");
}
```

Comment: so simple!  Thank you!

Comment: @George Sherman So...  Accepting it is the right way to go :-)